# Number of products required to multiply polynomial coefficients

Tags: complexity-theory

I am wondering about the claim from the book "Probability and computing" that the number of products required to multiply monomial coefficients is $\Theta(d^2)$, where $d$ is the number of monomials that forms the polynomial
$$P(x)  = (x-a_1)(x-a_2)\cdots(x-a_d).$$
I think this answer is wrong and it takes $\Theta(2^d)$ instead.

Could someone explain this, please?

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean by "multiply polynomial coefficients" in this context. Do you mean multiplying two polynomials (expressed as coefficients)? In which case you're both wrong. You can multiply polynomials using the Karatsuba algorithm, which takes $O(d^{\log_2 3})$ time, or the FFT, which takes $O(d \log d)$ time. Can you give your reasoning as to why you think it takes $\Theta(2^d)$ time?

Comment: No i am tolking about number of multiplications required to transform the plynome to its canonical form

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider the following algorithm:

- Start with $P = 1$.
- For $i=1,\ldots,d$: replace $P$ with $P \cdot (x - a_i)$.

At step $i$, the polynomial $P$ has degree $i-1$, and so we need to compute
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{i-1} p_j x^j (x - a_i) = \sum_{j=1}^i p_{j-1} x^j - \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} a_i p_j x^j = -a_i p_0 + \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} (p_{j-1} - a_i p_j) x^j + p_{i-1} x^i.
$$
As you can see, this requires $i-1$ products. Summing over all $i$, we obtain $\frac{d(d-1)}{2} = \Theta(d^2)$ products.

In fact, using FFT we can improve on this. FFT multiplies two degree $m$ polynomial using only $\Theta(m\log m)$ products. A straightforward divide and conquer approach results in the following recurrence for the number of products:
$$ T(d) = 2T(d/2) + \Theta(d\log d). $$
The solution is $T(d) = \Theta(d\log^2 d)$.

Answer (score 5):

Two polynomials of degree n, giving by their coefficients, can be multiplied in O(n^2) using the trivial algorithm and in O (n log n) using FFT.

Now you need more than one multiplication. You start with n first degree polynomials, you get n/2 2nd degree polynomials, then n/4 4th degree polynomials, etc. All those multiplications will be O(n^2) using the primitive algorithm and O(n log^2 n) using FFT.

I think a bigger problem may be that the coefficients get very large very fast, so a multiplication is not a primitive operation

Also the FFT method isn’t very efficient for small degrees so you would multiply small degree polynomials in pairs using the naive algorithm then switch to FFT when it becomes more efficient.